# Python multiprocess how to return value before blocking code

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I multiprocess a function imported from a script.My problem is that that function at the end of the code blocks and shows a plot in a loop.Is there a way to catch a callback from function before that code blocks.

My code calling the function:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
#note that all this code is ruuning in PyQt thread
def callback(return_value):
    #here catch a signal or smt before code blocks
    #this as is will execute after the code unblocked



pool = Pool(processes=1)
pool.apply_async(my_funct,multiple my_funct_args,callback = callback)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

My blocking function:

```
#do some stuff not blocking the code and finally
.......
#here somehow pass a signal
plot.show()#that will block the code before callback can run
return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue with Pipe() but anyway stefan thx.

```
            parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
            p = Process(target = plot_map,args =(self.list_paths_map,self.var_map_type,self.var_map_colour,self.var_map_reso,self.var_map_rivers,
                            self.var_map_countries,self.var_map_great,self.var_map_night,self.var_map_night_hours,
                            self.var_map_night_mins,self.lats_ortho,self.lons_ortho,self.var_map_night_days,child_conn))
            p.daemon=True
            p.start()
            parent_conn.recv()
            self.closedlg_2.emit()
            self.enable_all.emit(True)
            p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-listener's-clients for interprocess communication and send a message before calling the blocking function